# how to set the default value of a property in a sharepoint web part

Tags: sharepoint-2010

My question is: how can I set the default value to a web part property in sharepoint so that is shows up in the tool pane?

And how do I save the changes to the property after the user has changed the default value? So far it is not working.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are defined by marking the property with the descent Value.
Have a look here
http://allaboutmoss.com/2010/04/05/webpart-development-part-4-creating-custom-web-part-properties/
the they are serialized to xml and stored where the Webart is implemented (a webpartpage i.E)
HAve a look with designer at a webpartpage and you´ll see

Comment: the link is dead.